# Generating a new secrets.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to clone a rails repository from github, but it doesn't have a secrets.yml file.  When I try to run the app from rails server, I get the error

Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`

I know what the structure of the file is supposed to look like, but is there a way for me to generate keys to use the development environment?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This rake task generate secret for you:

```
bundle exec rake secret
```

> Generate a cryptographically secure secret key (this is typically
>   used to generate a secret for cookie sessions)

All rake tasks:

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

The secrets.yml file(note the indentation):

```
development:
  secret_key_base: d140269c106b6d064cdd670a5aace0bbbb1400de545377a47836dbdab8104f2fdf0ab87e6b7982819d1bcc2ccf6a5f093985a0895970f01f30b0b15378a090e9
  some_key: 338a3312d82
  some_secret: f5d9c3214e7b
  other_environment: development
  other_password: password

production:
  secret_key_base: d140269c106b6d064cdd670a5aace0bbbb1400de545377a47836dbdab8104f2fdf0ab87e6b7982819d1bcc2ccf6a5f093985a0895970f01f30b0b15378a090e9
  some_key: 338a3312d82
  some_secret: f5d9c3214e7b
  other_environment: development
  other_password: password
```

Comment: your rails server run in the development environment?

Comment: I made the mistake of using a file called secrets.sample.yml instead of secrets.yml.  It's working now.  Thanks for the answer, that command was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Thanks, had to wait for StackOverflow's timer to allow me to do so

Answer (score 16):

In Rails 5 you can simply type.

```
rails secret
```

This will generate a new key for you. Just copy the key and put it in your `secrets.yml` file

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <Generated key>
```